# php convert a string into multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have seen many posts on here about converting a multi dimensional array into a string but not the other way around so I have a question to ask. I have got the following string of data which is retrieved from a JQuery array via a post:

```
["enquiry@gardengamesltd.co.uk, sales@gardengamesltd.co.uk","http://www.gardengamesltd.co.uk/acatalog/contactus.html"],["enquiry@gardengames.com","http://www.gardengames.com/contact/"],["info@gardengamesandleisure.com","http://www.gardengamesandleisure.com/ContactUs.aspx"],["playtime@kentgardengameshire.com","http://www.kentgardengameshire.com/contact-us.html"],["sales@gardengamesuk.com","http://www.gardengamesuk.com/contact.php"],["team@gardenknightgames.com","http://www.gardenknightgames.com/contact/"],["ajax-loader@2x.gif","http://www.just-garden-games.co.uk/"]
```

What I am wanting to do is convert it into an array which looks like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Email] => enquiry@gardengamesltd.co.uk, sales@gardengamesltd.co.uk
            [FB] => http://www.gardengamesltd.co.uk/acatalog/contactus.html
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Email] => enquiry@gardengames.com
            [FB] => http://www.gardengames.com/contact/
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Email] => info@aaeventhire.com
            [FB] => http://www.aaeventhire.com/pricing/garden-games
        )

)
```

I realize I could use `$array = explode('","', $harvest_data);` however this is only going to give me a single level array and ideally I am wanting to keep email, fb inside an inner array.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to explode as you have, then loop that and explode the contents of that array, and combine it back.

Comment: I would just JSON encode the array, post it to PHP and then JSON decode it.

Comment: So I would explode by `],[` first then `","` second inside a foreach loop of the first exploded array? I was looking into this but I am not sure how to make an array once I have looped into the initial array

Comment: David your reply looks good, I'm just going to look around for an example of a JSON encode and decode

Comment: Javascript side: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON PHP Side: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is, your string is not valid JSON. Wrapping it in a pair of `[]`'s would work in this case so if the input always has this form, this would work:

```
$json_string = '[' . $your_string . ']';
$your_array = json_decode($json_string);
```

**However**, it would be best to make sure that your front-end / javascript posts valid JSON to begin with.

[Working example](http://codepad.org/0dc5b8TI).

Comment: The javascript was in fact posting valid JSON I simply stripped the outside `[]` while trying to explode, thanks for the help.